# How to get @font-face working in safari and mozilla (bigcartel) luna theme

Tags: css, fonts, bigcartel

I added a bit of css (@font-face)script in my Luna theme on Bigcartel. the font works but not in safari and mozilla where do I have to look to get this working in those browsers ?

here is the answer I followed and used the script from:

[Can I upload a custom font to big cartel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460096/can-i-upload-a-custom-font-to-big-cartel)

Comment: When you inspect element/use Firebug, does the CSS part give you a hint?

Comment: What versions of the browsers? What file type do the fonts have? Are you loading the fonts from another domain? In what way does it not work (the computer crashes, you get mojibake, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your webserver to allow font files to be loaded from a separate domain - if you check the Network tab in your browser's web inspector you'll likely see an error about it.

There's lots of good info on how to do that here: [How to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: To add this you need access to the .htaccess file at Big Cartel though right? So it cant be done?

Comment: @pinkp the actual font files will need to be hosted on a separate server outside of Big Cartel, and then modify that server's .htaccess to allow outside domains to load the fonts (if necessary) - Big Cartel doesn't allow custom font hosting or .htaccess modification.